# Sqoop import for Date datatype in avro fromat

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, avro

**My issues is the date is going as two days less

In SQL server the date is 2015-06-12 (date type is date) it gets converted to
String in hive table avro format the value is 2015-06-10.

Script used.

sqoop import  --connect "xxx" --query 'select * from dbo.tableName WHERE $CONDITIONS' --target-dir xxx --fields-terminated-by '\001' --split-by tableName.columnName1 -m 8 --as-avrodatafile --compression-codec snappy  --map-column-java columnName2=String,;

Comment: What version of Sqoop are you using?  And this is MS SQL Server, right?

Comment: Also, what are the timezones of your server and the machine you are invoking Sqoop on?

Comment: Sqoop version :  sqoop 1.4

Comment: Is there a difference between the server's date/clock and the data node? Remember that without specifying `-D mapreduce.map.java.opts=" -Duser.timezone=$tz"` (where `$tz` is server's timezone) Sqoop will interpret the timestamp (seconds since epoch) using the timezone of the datanode.

Comment: The machine where I invoke sqoop has time zone MST. But SQL server I dont have access.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how a 48 hour discrepancy could be accounted for when the long is interpreted as MST. That big a difference would need to be more the +12 and -12. You might be able to tell the server timezone with `DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone`. Other than timezone differences nothing else is coming to mind...

Answer (score 1):

I think I might know.  MS SQL driver has a [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2652061) with Java 7.  Either downgrade to Java 6, update/upgrade your SQL Server driver, or upgrade to [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) (I've noticed better performance with jTDS anyway).

Comment: Glad we could sort it out.  Could you please accept my answer?